# Blank Screen on 18.04 - Razer Blade Stealth 13 (2020)

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation

Specifications:

- I7 1065G7
- NVIDIA GTX 1650 TI
- 16Gb ram
- 1tb Nvme SSD
- 13" 1920*1080 @120hz

Ubuntu distribution: Ubuntu 18.04 downloaded from Ubuntu.

I am currently trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my Razer Blade Stealth 13 (2020) but everytime I load Ubuntu via USB, I get a blank screen. I have tried things such as the `nomodeset` parameter but still end up with a blank screen. Does anyone know what the problem may be and how to solve it? Thank you in advance!